Sinc droop in a simple sampling mixer
This question is about the conceptual interpretation of a track-and-hold mixing operation implemented conceptually below, where an output $y(t)$ tracks an input $x(t)$ for half of a period $T_{LO}$ and holds the previous value for the second half of the period.
The text shows a decomposition of $y(t)$ into two separate signals $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ and then derives each of their Fourier transforms. Since there's a lot of text here, I've uploaded the relevant pages I'm referring to here.
My main question centers around this passage, in the boxed paragraph on the last page:

Note the subtle difference between $Y1(f)$ and $Y2(f)$: in the former, each replica of $X(f)$ is simply scaled by a factor, whereas in the latter, each replica experiences a “droop” due to the sinc envelope.

I don't really understand how the two cases are particularly unique. In the case of $Y_1(f)$, yes it's true that the spectrum of $X(f)$ is convolved with a bunch of impulses, but each one of those impulses were themselves scaled by a sinc since they originally came from the spectrum of a rectangular function in time with a sinc-shaped transform. $Y_2(f)$ is perhaps more directly experiencing a sinc scaling, but are these cases actually fundamentally different?
As a secondary question, I'm unable to exactly reproduce equation (6.13) as I seem to have an extra factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ on the RHS. (6.13) mixes transforms in Hz and rad/s, so maybe I'm missing something.
Thanks very much for any help.

